# How to forbid Newtonsoft.Json convert int on bool

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, deserialization

How to forbid converting any integer to a bool field. Now I am sending a query from postman to my asp .net application and in the bool type field I enter 123 but i want execute situation so that deserialization fails and returns an error that it is impossible to enter such a value?

```
"ownerData": [{
            "ownerNumber": "12345678",
            "maritalState": "4",
            "separateMarriageEstates":123,
            "personInHouseHold": 2,
            "education": "WYZ"
        }
```

```
public class Model
{
        [DataMember(Name = "ownerNumber", IsRequired = true, Order = 0)]
        public string OwnerNumber{ get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "maritalState", IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
        public string MaritalState { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "separateMarriageEstates", IsRequired = true, Order = 2)]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(BooleanJsonConverter))]
        public bool? SeparateMarriageEstates { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "personInHouseHold", IsRequired = true, Order = 3)]
        public int? PersonInHouseHold { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "education", IsRequired = true, Order = 4)]
        public string Education { get; set; }
}


public class BooleanJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            switch (reader.Value.ToString().ToLower().Trim())
            {
                case "true":
                case "yes":
                case "y":
                case "1":
                    return true;
                case "false":
                case "no":
                case "n":
                case "0":
                    return false;
            }

            // If we reach here, we're pretty much going to throw an error so let's let Json.NET throw it's pretty-fied error message.
            return new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer().Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            if (objectType == typeof(String) || objectType == typeof(Boolean))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share with us a sample json and a data model into which you want to deserialize the json?

Comment: Can you please share with us the code of `BooleanJsonConverter`?

Comment: You can remove the line `return new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer().Deserialize(reader, objectType);` and have the method raise an exception instead.

Comment: I second @sephiroth. In the comment you write you're going to throw an error. Then instead you default to the standard Newtonsoft serialization insead.
Replace that line with something like this: `throw new JsonSerializationException($"Cannot convert '{valueString}' to a boolean");` and you're golden.

Comment: Also please be aware that `CanConvert` is NOT called if you specify your converter via the `JsonConverterAttribute`.